# getting unexpected result when using Python's struct.pack method

Tags: python, shellcode, endianness

When i'm using python's struct.pack method i'm getting a weird result.
The code looks like this:

```
>>> struct.pack('<i', 0x01d1f23a)
```

The result i'm trying to get is the hex address converted to little endian ("<").
EDITED:
Equivalent to Perl (sorry for the print's, don't know perl)

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
my $eip = pack('V',0x01ccf23a); 
print "$eip[0]";
print "$eip[1]";
print "$eip[2]";
print "$eip[3]";
```

the result is: 582422041

I need to achieve the same result with python.

Comment: So what result did you expect, and what did you get instead?

Comment: Can you explain why the colon is a problem? What are you using the output string for? Do you want a string of length 4 containing the four characters `chr(0x3a)`, `chr(0xf2)`, `chr(0xd1)` and `chr(0x01)`, or do you want a string of length 16 that looks like `\x3a\xf2\xd1\x01` when printed? (And if the latter, *why*?)  Or something else?

Comment: Hey mark i've just edited my question. I want the result to be like this: 582422041

Comment: @Igalname: Okay, that makes no sense to me (why would you want to run all the numbers together like that?), but if that's really what you want then `''.join(str(x) for x in struct.pack('<i', 0x01ccf23a))` (in Python 3) or `''.join(str(ord(x)) for x in struct.pack('<i', 0x01ccf23a))` (in Python 2) would do the trick.

Comment: @MarkDickinson Hey Mark, the explanation ive written is bad i fixed it now. I want to put hex characters in a variable. like this EIP = "\x3a"+"\xf2"+"\xd1"+"\x01". But instead writing every single hex char and concatenating between then i want to achieve this with some function that equivalent to perl pack function

Comment: @MarkDickinson Found what i've been looking for: string1 = str(struct.pack('<L',0x01D1F23A)) thanks!

Comment: @Igalname: Did you try printing that? If you did, you'll notice that it still starts with `':'` (and in fact it's identical to `struct.pack('<i', 0x01D1F23A)`).

Answer (score 1):

Everything seems to be fine:

```
>>> struct.pack('<i', 0x01d1f23a)
b':\xf2\xd1\x01'
```

Most significant byte `01` is stored at the highest memory address, thus giving little endian. The only thing I may notice is that `b'\x3a'` looks like `:` because it is a valid ASCII symbol.

If the answer doesn't addresses your issue, please update your post with details.

**Edit**

In order to have the number represented as a sequence of bytes in hex form, without conversion to ASCII, use the following line:

```
>>> ' '.join(hex(b) for b in struct.pack('<i', 0x01d1f23a))
'0x3a 0xf2 0xd1 0x1'
```

Use `str` instead of `hex` to get decimal representation.

```
>>> ' '.join(str(b) for b in struct.pack('<i', 0x01d1f23a))
'58 242 209 1'
```

Comment: the " : " is the problem, i need the hex values to stay as hex values and converted to ASCII. Similar to perl pack('V', ) method